# Checking if a Residual Stress Field Achieves Mechanical Equilibrium

Tags: mechanical-engineering, applied-mechanics, stresses, finite-element-method

Suppose I told you the Cauchy Stress Tensor at every point inside a chunk of metal. And, yes, I know this means that I would need to tell you about an infinite number of points - let's ignore that right now. Then I asked you to tell me if that stress field is in mechanical equilibrium. How would you check if that stress field is in mechanical equilibrium? Would you use finite element analysis? Do there exist analytical techniques for checking if a stress field achieves mechanical equilibrium?

Comment: Could you describe a case, where the stress would not be at equilibrium?

Comment: We're estimating a workpiece's residual stress field using incomplete information. Imagine this situation: I know the residual stress field in the upper half of a part, but I don't know it in the lower half of the part. I use some estimation technique to make an educated guess about what the residual stress field in the lower half of the part, but my estimation technique does not guarantee that the estimation will produce a residual stress field which is in equilibrium. I would like to check if it is in equilibrium or not. Right now, the only way I know how to do this is to run FEM.

Comment: Why don't you just add condition of equilibrium into the estimation technique? Even in such case, the resulting stress may still not be the same as in reality, but it will be more plausible. You can use [equilibrium equations for element](https://www.continuummechanics.org/equilibrium.html).

Comment: Adding that condition to the estimation technique is nontrivial and computationally expensive. But let me think about it. Thank you for the suggestions!